# gitlab: Specify the project with PROJECT_ID={number} or PROJECT_PATH

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-rake

My research group uses gitlab to manage projects for which each researcher is working on. The projects server is accessible on `https://gitlab.com/our-lab-name`. My specific project as accessible on: `https://gitlab.com/our-lab-name/my-project-name`

I would like to remove unreferenced LFS files, so I proceeded as far GitLab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/cleanup.html).

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:cleanup:orphan_lfs_file_references PROJECT_PATH="https://gitlab.com/our-lab-name/my-project-name"

I, [2022-05-09T12:33:40.101636 #30556]  INFO -- : Specify the project with PROJECT_ID={number} or PROJECT_PATH={namespace/project-name}
```

Then supplied my project ID (Project ID: 14xxxx41):

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:cleanup:orphan_lfs_file_references PROJECT_ID=14xxxx41
I, [2022-05-09T12:45:23.865401 #32224]  INFO -- : Specify the project with PROJECT_ID={number} or PROJECT_PATH={namespace/project-name}
```

None seems to work.

What is your suggestion?

Comment: Are you using `gitlab.com` or a self-hosted GitLab instance?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by self-hosted, but we use a free account to manage projects.

Comment: If you are using `gitlab.com` you cannot use `gitlab-rake` commands.

Comment: Ah, I see, our projects are actually hosted at `https://gitlab.com/our-lab-name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gitlab-rake` commands are intended for use by self-hosted GitLab administrators only. Since you are using gitlab.com, you cannot use `gitlab-rake` commands to administrate your GitLab projects.

These commands are intended to be run directly on the GitLab server, which you would only have access to as an administrator of the server. In the case of GitLab.com, only certain GitLab.com employees can perform console escalations.

You'll notice the documentation states this feature is for self-managed customers only (that is, you run your own gitlab instance on your own servers) and is *not* available in GitLab SaaS (gitlab.com).

[image: self-managed]